# How to de-serialize JSON objects in C# which were sent by a JAVA program using jackson?

Tags: java, c#, json, serialization, jackson

I'm working on a project needing a .NET program and a JAVA program to interoperate via protocol.

The JAVA side uses Jackson to serialize simple JAVA objects (resulting in JSON-Packets having the concrete class as @class members).

But the .NET side uses different conventions for this - here the type is specified by __type members.

Can I massage the .NET side to accept JACKSON formatted packets? Changing the protocol format on the JAVA side would be suboptimal, because the protocol is already used elsewhere, so getting .NET to adapt would be preferred.

Currently I was looking at the .NET DataContractJsonSerializer - but it is also possible to employ a third party library on the .NET side if required.

Can JSON.NET offer this kind of flexibility? BTW, problems like assembly versions are not an issue here, so it is perfectly OK for the protocol to *not* send that information.

**EDIT** to make my intentions clearer, here some example code:

### JAVA side

```
package some.pkg;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)public abstract class EventBase {

  public final String superField;

  protected EventBase(final String superField) {
    this.superField = superField;
  }
}
```

#### A second JAVA package class

```
package some.pkg;

public final class EventA extends EventBase {

  public final int intFieldA;

  public EventA(final int intFieldA, final String superField) {
    super(superField);
    this.intFieldA = intFieldA;
  }

  private EventA() {this(0,null);}//for jackson
}
```

### JSON generated by Jackson

A JSON string generated by Jackson will look e.g. like

```
{
  "@class" : "some.pkg.EventA",
  "superField" : "S1",
  "intFieldA" : 1
}
```

### .NET

Here I have equivalent classes (with methods not shown here - this is a request/event protocol, and the request methods are stored in the packets themselves.

So here I expect something akin to

```
namespace some.pkg
{
  public sealed class EventA extends EventBase {

  public EventA(final int intFieldA, final String superField) : base(superField) {
    this.intFieldA=intFieldA;
  }

  [DataMember]
  public int  fieldA { get; private set; }
}
```

... superclass and other subclasses of EventBase elied.

The problem here for me is Jackson's way of signaling the class, either via @c or via @class, versus Microsoft's standart "__type" attribute, or JSON.NET's "$type".

**Edited - Summary**

OK, the answer with switching $type versus @class before resp. after the .NET serializer does it's deed works rather nicely (as long as the magical Strings @class and $type are not used elsewhere as payload data).

A look into JSON.NET's sources showed me that the $type descriminator field is a const string, so changing that would require us to use a patched JSON.NET library, which looks to be more work than just changing the offending strings before resp. after the JsonReader/Writer classes do their deed.

Comment: Did you actually try JSON.NET? I think that would work for you

Comment: Dear Wolfgang, please try to use code formatting for code; also, insert more paragraphs. This is barely readable.

Comment: @Much Overflow - I've only started looking into JSON.NET, I did not (yet) try it out.

Comment: @class is pretty much set in stone, as the protocol is already used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure about converting default naming conventions of JSON.NET. But if I were you, I would use a "JSON interceptor" function like the following

```
public static class JSONInterceptor {
    public static string sanitizeJSON(string originalJSONFromJava)
    {
        //add any other validation checks here as you may see fit. ex: null checks
        return originalJSONFromJava.replace("@class", "$type");
    }
}
```

and then use it to generate the .NET class like the following

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EventA>(JSONInterceptor.sanitizeJSON(originalJSONFromJava));
```

I haven't tried this myself yet. but the idea is to show you that this could be done in the following way, too

Comment: Well, this trick works, at least if neither $type nor @class are used elsewhere :-)

Comment: For additional safety you coud replace "\"@class\" :" with "\"@type\" :" I hardly doubt your json would contain those exact string elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data format and is equal to all languages, even if you use Tex to generate json data.
In .net the easiest (imho) way for deserializing json object is using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
Example:
Java side

```
public class A {
  @JsonProperty("afield")
  public String afield;
}
```

Then declare an equal class in C#

```
public class A {
    [JsonProperty("afield")]
    public string afield {get;set;}
}
```

So when you receive the json object A from java side you only just need call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(stringreceived)` to get the object.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is because this (existing) protocol basically sends polymorphic objects over the wire, which must be de-serialized into a matching class on the other sides. Just sending the data alone is not the big problem here.

Comment: JSON.NET indeed supports deserialisation of polymorphic objects. Have a read at this http://kirmir.com/2014/05/16/polymorphic-serialization-using-newton-json-net-in-httpcontent/

Comment: Is it possible have an example of json object? @WolfgangLiebich

Comment: @Tinwor - I extended my initial post with some samples.

Answer (score 0):

There is a kind of equivalent of the Jackson annotion for C# that works with JSON.net and [JsonSubTypes](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes):

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "@class")]
[JsonSubtypes.KnownSubType(typeof(EventA), "some.pkg.EventA")]
public class EventBase {

}
```

see more possibilites in the [readme](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes/blob/master/README.md)